# What would be needed to read USB keyboard input on the 8266 or ESP32 chip?

Tags: esp8266

My objective is to read input from a Keyboard Wedge device (i.e. Hand Scanner) which will emulate a keyboard entry and a carriage return and then broadcast that information to the cloud.

I think I may be good from a software perspective (once I figure out how to capture the input) to make that happen but not certain if I can capture that input directly using an OTG cable directly into the 8266 or if I need some other board to use in conjunction with the 8266 to capture this information.

As an alternative I could use a Pie W but I'd like to see if I can produce something even cheaper when you consider all the accessories involved etc... and like the 8266 and the ESP32 as options.

Comment: You will need a microcontroller circuit with USB host connected to your ESPxx. And a firmware for it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Thank you for the comment. I'm a bit new to this space. Would something like this be what I want?
http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/usb-host-keyboard

Comment: Looks interesting and could work from the first glance...

Comment: If you can go bluetooth, you can use bluetooth HID with a bluetooth keyboard

Comment: @laptop2d so you are thinking something like this: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9434 hooks to the USB KB Wedge Device and then use Bluetooth HID on the chip?

Comment: @JosephU. Just buy a bluetooth keyboard, the esp32 has bluetooth built in https://gist.github.com/sabas1080/93115fb66e09c9b40e5857a19f3e7787

Comment: @laptop2d I'm trying to use it with a family of devices similar to this one https://www.barcode-arena.com/motorola-ls2208-barcode-scanner.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwxYLoBRCxARIsAEf16-vE-BiyZVqhqYOGcwURZ_l6m0zACr0mghaQ_OmH966lZuGG-lNGLpgaAmAcEALw_wcB 
That all have a USB Wedge functionality that emulates a keyboard.